# Historical Questions

Tags: discussion, scope

**Is it appropriate to ask historical questions about the great outdoors on our forums?**

For instance, I have had no luck answering the following question:

> What gear did John Muir actually take on long trips?

As a Californian, John Muir is *the* legend of the outdoors. But the stories around what gear he took backpacking hardly seem plausible (no food, but also no hunting equipment?) I want a solid gear list.

Even ignoring the specifics of that question, are historical questions about the great outdoors and survival fit for our forums?

Comment: I would venture to say no, since we are not a historical site. Am curious though, what others think.

Comment: It's a fair point. I won't be crushed if people nix the idea. Just thought I'd ask.

Comment: Jolly, Ben C. answered this on rec.backcountry. ;-) http://www.backpackinglight.com/cgi-bin/backpackinglight/testimony_into_the_unknown_with_sturdy_footwear.html#.UlYBp2Tk_E0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it is appropriate to ask historical questions related to the great outdoors. It adds value and creativity to the site.