# Are questions about fictional subjects on topic on Outdoors

Tags: discussion, scope

Referring specifically to [this question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/17832/can-a-ropebucket-used-to-gather-water-from-a-well-be-kept-outside-tied-to-this?noredirect=1#comment44917_17832) The question is research for a fictional world that has technology in line with that of medieval times.

Many believe it is on topic, as its been decided though [This meta Question](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/would-questions-about-historic-outdoorsmanship-be-on-topic-here) that historical questions are on topic. They draw the conculsion because the question is restricting the answers to medieval times, its historical, therefore on topic.

The question is actually one about World Building and was rejected on that site, with the OP being pointed to Outdoors.SE. However, I believe its even more Off topic on outdoors.se

I do not believe it is an Outdoors type question. Our own help screen states

> "What topics can I ask about here?
>
> "The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange is for people who love outdoor
>   activities, excursions, and outdoorsmanship. It is about activities
>   that occur in the Great Outdoors, including but not limited to: ...

I fail to see how world building fits into the general thesis of this statement. Sure, its about the out doors, but if we accept that an imagainary well in an imaginary world is On topic, is not anything we can imagine that is 'outdoors' On topic on this site?

The Great Outdoors is already a very broad topic with a very diverse set of participants with huge breath of interests. The main stay of what we are is the activity of being outdoors. This is nothing about the activity of being outdoors, its about what happens if an imaginary inanimate object is placed outdoors in an imaginary world.

The fundamental question is broader than this on. Its when do we draw a line for questions, that while interesting and valid, are really not about what many think when they here the phrase "The Great Outdoors"

Comment: We already have at least two questions where the asker is writing a story, https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/17101/would-a-gunshot-echo-in-a-cave https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/15606/collecting-plant-foodstuff-in-the-canadian-wilderness-of-alberta-during-winter

Answer (score 5):

If you exclude the reasons why that question was asked, it is very simply a question about whether the rope and bucket should be stored in the well or outside it.

As many off-grid and country-living folks use wells to get water, and this very much sits in the Outdoor arena, this can be on topic here.

Comment: How does the question help these people with the medieval restriction precluding modern technology.  I know many people who are supplied by well water, not one of them uses a rope and bucket of any description to access it.

Comment: @mattnz You've got a point.  Scanning [Wells in Third World Countries](https://www.google.com/search?q=Wells+in+third+world+countries&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicypCKq4DYAhVI42MKHbEfBm8Q7AkIkQE&biw=1281&bih=567), I see pictures of newly constructed wells, none of which have ropes and buckets.  Older wells do.

Answer (score 3):

That **isn't a fictional questio**n about an imaginary person in an imaginary world, that is a **real** question about how **real people** in the **real world** solved a **real problem**  so that the OP can write a **realistic story.**

Now if it was about [crumple horned snorkacks](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157852/does-the-crumple-horned-snorkack-exist) which are imaginary creatures made up by imaginary people in a fictional world, then yes the question would be off-topic.

Side note:

Personally, I would be much happier if authors took the time to ask how their characters would realistically do things in the outdoors.

The worst I ever saw was where the characters went down the rapids to get around the dam blocking upstream travel.

Comment: What's your problem?  So they took a 24,000 mile detour, so what? :)