# Can we open the historical footwear question?

Tags: discussion, scope

I just came across this [question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/13379/what-did-mountaineerers-wear-in-the-19th-century) again and I think we should reopen it.  We have two questions on meta [here](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/would-questions-about-historic-outdoorsmanship-be-on-topic-here) and [here](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/414/historical-questions?noredirect=1&lq=1) that say that historical questions are on topic and a number of comments on the deleted [meta question](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/817/what-did-mountaineerers-wear-in-the-19th-century/818#818) that suggest its on-topic.

I think the user is still around and would hopefully be able to provide more detail.

If anything we probably shouldn't have migrated it to meta...

Comment: Yup.  I voted to re-open.

Comment: Yes, it should be reopened.  Funny thing is, I think I answered it, or at least did research on it.

Answer (score 3):

I agree it should not have been migrated to meta - I rejected that migration as off topic, which pinged it back to main.

Pop a reopen vote on it, and see if others agree.

Answer (score 1):

The main space question is now open.

I have voted to re-open the answer on the meta version https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/817/what-did-mountaineerers-wear-in-the-19th-century/818#818 so that we can ping the author and ask them to repost their answer to the now open main space question.

Comment: Better idea go ping the author of on deleted answer on one of their existing posts

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh, good idea [done](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/16028/what-is-this-knot-that-is-used-on-ice-axe-leashes/16030#16030)